# has_many with sum active record

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to  :category
      has_many  :order_items, dependent: :destroy
    end


class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```

I need to list all product with their sum of quantity from order_item and sum of their total_price

```
Product
id    name
1    product_1

OrderItem
product_id order_id quantity total_price
 1            1      10        200
 1            2      10        200

for example expecting output should be
name       quantity   total_price
product_1  20         400
```

Comment: Thanks @jarlh, is that possible like Product.joins(:order_items).sum("order_items.quantity") ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select p.name, sum(o.quantity) as quantity, sum(o.total_price) as total_price
from Product p
  join OrderItem o on p.id = o.product_id
group by p.name
```

Comment: Thanks @jarlh. a small modification "select p.name, sum(o.quantity) as quantity, sum(o.total_price) as total_price from products p join order_items o on p.id = o.product_id group by p.name"

Comment: how can I added where condition here, I tried "select p.name, sum(o.quantity) as quantity, sum(o.total_price) as total_price from products p join order_items o on p.id = o.product_id group by p.name  WHERE (o.created_at = '2015-07-07')" ?

Comment: Just put WHERE before GROUP BY.

Comment: Thanks that Worked. "select p.name, sum(o.quantity) as quantity, sum(o.total_price) as total_price from products p join order_items o on p.id = o.product_id WHERE (DATE(o.created_at) = '2015-07-07') group by p.name"

Answer (score 2):

Try this query

```
select a.name,sum(quantity) as quantity ,sum(total_price) as total_price from 
Product a
join OrderItem b on a.id=b.product_id
Group by a.name
```

Comment: Thanks @Mukesh Kalgude. a small modification in your query to help others "select a.name,sum(b.quantity) as quantity ,sum(b.total_price) as total_price from 
products a join order_items b on a.id=b.product_id Group by a.name"

Comment: sorry I'm not able to select two correct answer. since he replied first I accepted his response. Thanks

Comment: how can I added where condition here, I tried "select p.name, sum(o.quantity) as quantity, sum(o.total_price) as total_price from products p join order_items o on p.id = o.product_id group by p.name WHERE (o.created_at = '2015-07-07')" ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this for active records query. just verify your column,table name and associations you can used like:

```
   OrderItem.joins(:product).select("products.name as name,sum(total_price) as total_price , sum(quantity) as total_quantity").group("order_items.product_id").as_json
```

Answer (score 1):

```
p = Product.first
p.order_items.sum(:quantity)
```

I hope this may also help